# How to solve this quadratic tensor equation? (Scalar equivalent would be finding a square root.)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a quadratic tensor equation here, and I have no idea how to solve it:

$$
A_{ijk}x_jx_k = b_i
$$

Here, $A$, and $b$ are constants, and $x$ is the unknown. The scalar equivalent of this equation would be:

$$
ax^2 = b
$$

which is solved by $x = \pm\sqrt{b/a}$.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or where to look for a solution method?

Comment: Do we know that $A_{ijk} = \bar{A}_{ikj}$? If so this becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Just another question, why can we not just take $j = k$, then solve by saying $x_j = \pm \sqrt{\frac{b_i}{A_{ijj}}}$. I'm not too experienced with tensor mechanics.

Comment: @eyeballfrog No, not in general.

Comment: @NambiarM. Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation We're summing over $j$ and $k$ separately.

Answer (score 2):

For every $i\leq p$, $x,b_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (vectors) and  $A_i\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (square matrices).

Then one has $p$ equations of degree $2$ in the $n$ unknowns $x_i$ that can be written as

$x^TA_ix=b_i,i\leq p$.

There are softwares that work about polynomials of degree $2$. Yet, it can be difficult to obtain all the many solutions.