# References or solution methods for $A\left(\frac{\tt1}{x}\right)=\lambda x$

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods

$
\def\norm{\mathop{\operatorname{norm}}\limits}
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
$Let $A$ be a matrix with non-negative elements, and denote the elementwise
inverse of a positive vector $(x_k>0)\,$ as
$$\fracLR{\o}{x}$$

Then I am interested in solutions of the equation
$$\eqalign{
A \fracLR{\o}{x} = \l x \\
}$$
Its structure is similar to the standard Eigenvalue Problem.

This equation occurs in models of *Economic Fitness* wherein the matrix
describes a bipartite network of countries $(c)$ and the products $(p)$ that they export.
The matrix $(M)$ is a set of modified Balassa Indexes (aka$\,$ *comparative advantages*).

Since $M$ is rectangular, the economic model employs a pair of proportional equations
$$\eqalign{
M  \fracLR{\o}{p} &\propto c &\qiq \l\,c = M  \fracLR{\o}{p} \\
M^T\fracLR{\o}{c} &\propto p &\qiq \l\,p = M^T\fracLR{\o}{c} \\
}$$
but these can be combined into a single matrix equation by defining
$$\eqalign{
A &= \m{0&M \\ M^T&0}, \qquad 
x &= \m{c \\ p}, \qquad 
\l &= \m{\l_cI & 0 \\ 0 & \l_pI} \\
}$$

Economists found that a simple power iteration
$$\eqalign{
x_+ &=  \norm_{c,\,p}\LR{A\fracLR{\o}{x}} \\
}$$
converges for most (although not all) matrices derived from real-world trade data.

$\big($**NB**: $\,$The custom norm function normalizes the $(c,p)$ vectors independently$\big)$

To handle divergent matrices, they add a small
bias term (reminiscent of Google's PageRank algorithm)
$$\eqalign{
x_+ &= \norm_{c,\,p}\LR{A\fracLR{\o}{x}+\b{\o}} \\\\
}$$
Are there better algorithms than these simple iterations?

Is this equation featured in some sub-field of Linear Algebra or Numerical Analysis?

I've explored
*Generalized Eigenvalue/Eigenvectors, Nonlinear Eigenvalue/Eigenvectors, Pseudo-Eigenvalues, Pseudo-Spectra, etc*, but there is no mention of this particular equation.

Comment: If you rewrite your equation as $\frac{1}{x}=Ax$, then this becomes a quadratic system of equations.  How big of a system are you talking about to solve here?

Comment: You could try to solve the related equation $x = Av$ with the constraint $x^Tv = n$. Then your solutions are a subset of these solutions.

Comment: A [recent paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.12356.pdf) has answered my question. The key is to reformulate the equations as a _Sinkhorn-Knopp_ iteration instead of an eigenvalue problem. This is closely related to the _Iterative Proportional Fitting_ algorithm used in statistics.  The paper also contains references to many related articles on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=1/x$. Then:

$$\frac{1}{y_i} = \sum_j A_{ij}y_j$$

So for all $i$,

$$
y_i\sum_j A_{ij} y_j = 1
$$

Define the tensor $B$ by letting $B_{ijk} = A_{ij}\delta_{ik}$, then the equation becomes:

$$
\sum_j\sum_k B_{ijk}y_jy_k = c_i
$$

for all $i$, where $c_i=1$. There is apparently software available to solve such a quadratic equation (see [How to solve this quadratic tensor equation? (Scalar equivalent would be finding a square root.)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3130808/how-to-solve-this-quadratic-tensor-equation-scalar-equivalent-would-be-finding)). Your problem may have structure that makes it easier than this general problem however.