# Solving non-linear equations of the form $\mathbf x = A f(\mathbf x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

Let $A$ be a real, invertible $n\times n$ matrix. I am interested in finding the vectors $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb R^n$ that solve the following equation:

$$\mathbf x = A \tanh(\mathbf x)$$

where the $\tanh$ is applied element-wise. More generally, we can consider other kinds of non-linearities instead of the $\tanh$ (but always applied element-wise).

Is there a generic approach to studying the solutions of these type of equations? Probably exploiting the eigen decomposition of $A$?

I added the tag "reference-request" in case someone can suggest relevant references to the literature.

Comment: Let $y=\tanh(x)$ be an Eigenvector associated to the Eigenvalue $\lambda$. In general, $\text{artanh}(y)=A y=\lambda y$ cannot hold.

Comment: The eigenvalue-like equation $A\cdot{f}(x) = \lambda x$ can often be solved via power iteration (or inverse interation) for the dominant eigenpair, but it's unlikely that $\lambda=1.\;$

Comment: @greg Is there some theory for these equations? Published material?

Comment: Apparently not.  A few months ago, I posed [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803165) but never received a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2D case, the equation takes the form $$\begin{cases}x=a f(x)+bf(y),\\y=cf(x)+df(y)\end{cases}$$

and after elimintation of $y$, we get a univariate nonlinear equation
$$\frac{x-af(x)}b=f\left(cf(x)+\frac db(x-af(x)\right).$$ We don't see any particular simplification nor connection with the Eigenvalues.

---

I have seen numerical cases with four distinct positive solutions.

Comment: Can you post an example with four positive solutions? I haven't found any.

Comment: @becko: sorry, I didn't keep the values. All four coefficients were in range $[0,2]$ as far as I recall.