# Solution for non-linear equation system

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm looking for a direction to solve the following non-linear equation system (solving for $X$):

We have vector $\textbf{X}=\{X_1,\dots, X_t\}$ and the following system:
$$X_i = \frac{1}{\sum_{j}^{T}X_j\beta_{ij}}$$
where $\beta_{ij}=\beta_{ji}$ and $\beta$ is a known matrix.

I start to look on specific case where $\textbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The solution for this case is:
$$\frac{X_1^2}{X_2^2}=\frac{\beta_{22}}{\beta_{11}}$$

I wasn't able to generalize this result to the general case of
$\space\textbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If it helps we can assume $\sum{X_i}=1$ and $X_i \geq 0 \space$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Making the substitutions
$$\beta\to A, \qquad X\to \frac 1x$$
transforms this into an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3803165) of mine.
None of the answers was better than the simple iterations
referenced in the question itself.